# Issue With Scrapy Cookie Implementation

Tags: python, cookies, scrapy

I have what I think is a correct implementation of a spider that overrides two in built functions.

parse_start_url() and parse()

When I run the spider with the custom overridden parse() function commented out.
The spider runs fine, aggregates links using SgmlLinkExtractor, all ok.

But when I uncomment the custom parse() function the spider runs without error, but there is no output, so it must be the handling of requests and responses between functions. Ok sure.

I have actually spent a few too many hours trying to get this to work, using different approaches  with overriding functions/ using InitSpider/BaseSpider structures etc. nothing ever seems to set cookies correctly.

I am on version 0.16.4 which is old, so perhaps there's an issue there?

*** SOLVED *** 
Nevermind, I just solved it with a deep breath and a little bit of luck.
Revisited the approach of 'no middleware', using CrawlSpider,  SgmlLinkExtractor() & overriding  make_requests_from_url()

So I removed the block of code that was supposed to override parse(),
and added this:

```
def make_requests_from_url(self, url):
    request = Request(url, cookies = {'somedomain.com.au+2':'national'}, dont_filter=True)
    return request
```

SPIDER:

```
from scrapy.contrib.exporter import JsonItemExporter
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import Rule,CrawlSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.shell import inspect_response
from scrapy.http.cookies import CookieJar
from TM.items import TMItem
import json
import time
import datetime
import re
import sys
import os

COOKIES_DEBUG = True
COOKIES_ENABLED = True
SPIDER_NAME = "TKComAuSpider"
SPIDER_VERSION = "1.0"

class TKComAuSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "TKComAuMusicSpecific"
    allowed_domains = ["domain.com.au"]

    global response_urls
    response_urls = []
    global site_section_category
    global master_items
    master_items = []

    start_urls = [ "http://some.domain.com.au/shows/genre.aspx?c=2048" ]

    rules = (Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(".*page=[0-9]+.*", ),
    restrict_xpaths=('//*[@id="ctl00_uiBodyMain_searchResultsControl_uiPaginateBottom_List"]/ul/li',))
    , callback="parse_it", follow = True),
    )


    def parse(self, response):
        request_with_cookies = Request(url=self.start_urls[0],cookies={'domain.com.au+2':'national'})
        print '\n\n'  + request_with_cookies.url + '\n\n'
        yield request_with_cookies


    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        list(self.parse_it(response))


    def parse_it(self, response):

        spider_name = "TKComAuMusicSpecific"

        doc_date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%y-%H:%M")
        items = []

        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

        # RESPONSE ASSIGNMENT #
        response_url = response.url
        response_urls.append(response_url)


  #      cl = response.headers.getlist('Cookie')
  #     if cl:
  #          msg = "Sending cookies to: %s" % response_url  + os.linesep
  #          msg += os.linesep.join("Cookie: %s" % c for c in cl)
  #          log.msg(msg, spider=spider, level=log.DEBUG)



        # CUSTOM SITE_SECTION TO CREATE SPIDER CAT FROM RESPONSE_URL #
        site_section_category = re.sub(r'^.*//[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+([^.?]+).*$',r'\1', response.url).title().replace('/', '')

        spider_category = "TKTerms" + site_section_category
        file_name = 'out/' + spider_category + ".out"


        with open("log/response.log", 'a') as l:
                l.write(doc_date + ' ' + ' spider: ' + spider_name + '\nresponse_url: ' + response_url
                         + '\nsite_section_category: ' + site_section_category
                         + '\nspider_category: ' + spider_category + '\n')



        f = open(file_name, 'w')

        for site in hxs.select('//*[@class="contentEvent"]'):
            link = site.select('h6/a/@href').extract()
            title = site.select('h6/a/text()').extract()
            f.write("%s\n" % title)
            master_items.append({"title":title[0],"item_type":spider_category})
            yield TMItem(title=title[0],item_type=spider_category)
        f.close()





        json_out =  'json/' + spider_name + '.json'
        f = open(json_out, 'w')
        final_json = (json.dumps({"docs": [{"spider_name": SPIDER_NAME, "spider_version": SPIDER_VERSION},
                                 {"doc_title": spider_name, "doc_date": doc_date,
                                  "urls": response_urls}, master_items]}))
        f.write(final_json)
        f.close()



















2014-04-30 13:15:46+1000 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2014-04-30 13:15:46+1000 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2014-04-30 13:15:46+1000 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled item pipelines: JsonWriterPipelineLines, JsonWriterPipeline
2014-04-30 13:15:46+1000 [TKComAuMusicSpecific] INFO: Spider opened
2014-04-30 13:15:46+1000 [TKComAuMusicSpecific] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2014-04-30 13:15:46+1000 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 0.0.0.0:6024
2014-04-30 13:15:46+1000 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 0.0.0.0:6081
2014-04-30 13:15:46+1000 [TKComAuMusicSpecific] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://www.some.com.au/detection.aspx?rt=http%3a%2f%2fsome.domain.com.au%2fshows%2fgenre.aspx%3fc%3d2048> from <GET http://some.domain.com.au/shows/genre.aspx?c=2048>
2014-04-30 13:15:46+1000 [TKComAuMusicSpecific] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://some.domain.com.au/shows/genre.aspx?c=2048> from <GET http://www.some.com.au/detection.aspx?rt=http%3a%2f%2fsome.domain.com.au%2fshows%2fgenre.aspx%3fc%3d2048>
2014-04-30 13:15:46+1000 [TKComAuMusicSpecific] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://some.domain.com.au/shows/genre.aspx?c=2048> (referer: None)


http://some.domain.com.au/shows/genre.aspx?c=2048


2014-04-30 13:15:47+1000 [TKComAuMusicSpecific] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://some.domain.com.au/shows/genre.aspx?c=2048> (referer: http://some.domain.com.au/shows/genre.aspx?c=2048)


http://some.domain.com.au/shows/genre.aspx?c=2048


2014-04-30 13:15:47+1000 [TKComAuMusicSpecific] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2014-04-30 13:15:47+1000 [TKComAuMusicSpecific] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
        {'downloader/request_bytes': 1260,
         'downloader/request_count': 4,
         'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 4,
         'downloader/response_bytes': 146364,
         'downloader/response_count': 4,
         'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
         'downloader/response_status_count/302': 2,
         'finish_reason': 'finished',
         'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 30, 3, 15, 47, 108720),
         'log_count/DEBUG': 10,
         'log_count/INFO': 4,
         'request_depth_max': 2,
         'response_received_count': 2,
         'scheduler/dequeued': 4,
         'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 4,
         'scheduler/enqueued': 4,
         'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 4,
         'start_time': datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 30, 3, 15, 46, 220003)}
2014-04-30 13:15:47+1000 [TKComAuMusicSpecific] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: Apparently something else was probably not right when I last visited this approach.

Comment: When using `CrawlSpider`, you shouldn't override `parse()` unless you recreate and adapt the default `CrawlSpîder` behaviour (`CrawlSpider`'s `parse` method is where most of the "magic" happens. See [the warning in the docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules))

Comment: Sure, I am now even more aware of this since going back for another quick read. Playing with parse() was a last refuge really. I new what I was doing was wrong, it just seemed a perverse way to then expose something, because I didn't get it right any other way. I must've had something else quite wrong somewhere else at the time...  Thanks for the comment.